# Data not inserting to DB through WCF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I used to have a service with dataContracts and such that worked perfectly fine inserting data to the DB, this was the code:

```
public string InsertDetails(DeviceDetails deviceInfo)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=vurdevice;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            string Message;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO VR_Image (IMEINo, FileName, FileURL, Uploader, CarrierID, StorageName, FileSize, CreateDate) 
                                            values (@IMEINo, @FileName, @FileURL, @Uploader, @CarrierID, @StorageName, @FileSize, @CreateDate)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMEINo", deviceInfo.IMEINo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", deviceInfo.FileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileURL", deviceInfo.FileURL);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uploader", deviceInfo.Uploader);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarrierID", deviceInfo.CarrierID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StorageName", deviceInfo.StorageName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSize", deviceInfo.FileSize);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", deviceInfo.CreateDate);

            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                Message = deviceInfo.IMEINo + " Details inserted successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                Message = deviceInfo.IMEINo + " Details not inserted successfully";
            }
            con.Close();
            return Message;
        }
    }
```

I have now changed the service to take in a dataset from the client (client app and service is controlled here, so even though DataSets are NOT the way to go, it works since we have limited users). I have just ONE operationContract that will handle all datasets coming in and distribute them to the particular function it needs to go to, this is what the code looks like for the operationContract function:

```
public DataSet InterfaceService(string sInterface, DataSet dsIn)
    {
        System.Data.DataSet dsClean = new System.Data.DataSet();
        try
        {
            MethodInfo oMethod = null;
            oMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod(sInterface);
            System.Data.DataSet dsOut = (System.Data.DataSet)oMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { dsIn });
            dsClean.Merge(dsOut);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException(ex.Message, new FaultCode("An error has occurred. Please try again."));
        }
        return dsClean;
    }
```

And this is what the new Insert function looks like, I can't figure out WHY the data no longer gets inserted into the DB?!?!?!?

```
public DataSet InsertDetails(DataSet dsIn)
    {
        DataSet1.InsertInfoDataTable ds = new DataSet1.InsertInfoDataTable();
        ds.Merge(dsIn.Tables["InsertInfo"]);
        DataSet1.InsertInfoRow dr = ds.First();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=vurdevice;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO VR_Image (IMEINo, FileName, FileURL, Uploader, CarrierID, StorageName, FileSize, CreateDate) 
                                            VALUES (@IMEINo, @FileName, @FileURL, @Uploader, @CarrierID, @StorageName, @FileSize, @CreateDate)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMEINo", dr.IMEINo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", dr.FileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileURL", dr.FileURL);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uploader", dr.Uploader);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarrierID", dr.CarrierID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StorageName", dr.StorageName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSize", Convert.ToInt32(dr.FileSize));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", Convert.ToDateTime(dr.CreateDate));
            con.Close();
            return dsIn;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never execute your command.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @Golden Dragon, [facepalm] Thank you, it's crazy how you completely oversee the SMALLEST detail working for 10+ hours straight on something. Appreciate the help!!!

Comment: Wow, you use datasets in WCF? Datasets is for DAL. Definitely it is incorrect. Don't you have crashes when deserialising big data?

Comment: @marc_s, Thanks for the tip, I will change my code to follow the advice given on the article!

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri, The application only ever sends out a row through the DataSet so it's very minimal. Unfortunately, after I created the service with the proper DataContracts and members, I was instructed that that's NOT the way they want it done here. So that is the reason why I have to go this particular route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code snippet includes a call to execute your command but the second does not. Add a call to execute your sql command before you close it.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", Convert.ToDateTime(dr.CreateDate));
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // This line is missing
con.Close();
```